# Bring Debian to second Position in the GRUB Menu at startup

Tags: debian, system-installation, grub2

So, I currently have BOSS Linux and I am going to install Debian (currently installing right now)

And I want my older OS (BOSS linux), on the first position and the debian, (freshly installed) to be on the second. How do I do that?

Comment: Has Debian been put into the 1st position ?

Comment: yea, it would be on 1st position, i think so, will it be?

Comment: I don't know. Can't say I've installed Debian second before, but I'd assume that Debian wouldn't rearrange the Grub menu, and BOSS Linux would be the one to control the boot menu.

Comment: Because of the way the install works, the latest OS installed will always be the one who's boot menu is called by the BIOS, so Debian's GRUB should come up, with Debian as the first entry.

Comment: That's only if you choose to install the OS on 2 separate disks. If you install both on the same disk, you could tell Debian to not install Grub at all. You could then use BOSS Linux to reconfigure GRUB. From what I can tell from the Configuration files, if you have 2 installs of Linux on the same disk, it will put the distribution that's in the first partition first.

Comment: You cross-posted this question again: http://superuser.com/questions/674426/bring-debian-to-second-position-in-the-grub-menu-at-startup

Comment: Please don't cross-post on multiple SE sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force a specific order, you need to modify the file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`.
This file is what specifies which order the distros are listed.

If you want to force a certain distribution to be booted by default, then I would change `/etc/default/grub` and just set the GRUB_DEFAULT parameter to the one that you want to boot first, and then run `update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this AskUbuntu Q&A titled: [How do I change the grub boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order). You have 2 options:

1. Install a GUI, [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)
2. Edit a config file:

   ```
   $ sudo vim /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Then make changes such as...

   ```
   GRUB_DEFAULT=4
   ```

   then update grub's configuration:

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```

Be sure to check out that Q&A, I'm only paraphrasing the approaches here. Also there are methods for setting the default item in the grub menu, so that instead of always defaulting to item 0 (the 1st item on the list) it will instead default to another, say 4. That way if no one were to interact with the menu, the 5th item (4) would be booted, by default.

```
$ sudo grub-set-default 4
```

Comment: okay, if i will run `sudo update-grub`, from bosss linux, will the os, boss linux, will come at the first position?

Comment: @Utkarsh that depends on what you've set as the default either by running `grub-set-default` or by setting `GRUB_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.